# C programming error: expected '{' before string constant

Tags: c, string, constants

Here is the error I am receiving,

```
drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c: In function 'sdhci_msm_probe':
drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c:169:23: error: expected '{' before string constant
 #define HOST_MMC_MMC  "mmc0"
                       ^
drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c:2818:9: note: in expansion of macro 'HOST_MMC_MMC'
  struct HOST_MMC_MMC;
         ^
```

This issue is perplexing and I am very new to C so any help is appreciated.

Comment: We need to see the source code that is causing this issue. It's not easy to diagnose errors just from the error messages.

Comment: After pre-processing, you have code that reads `struct "mmc0";`  That doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: A string is not an identifier and can't be used as a type name.

Comment: @all thanks for the replies, this code is for a kernel and was very poorly coded originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `#define` preprocessor macro does direct token substitution.

So this:

```
struct HOST_MMC_MMC;
```

Turns into this after preprocessing:

```
struct "mmc0";
```

Which is invalid.

You'll need to either change the macro definition you have or change how you're using it here.

Comment: Thanks! The "HOST_MMC_MMC" did not need to be declared again in the later function so you were correct